# Bayesian Rating

Tags: php, rating, bayesian

```
$avg_num_votes = 18; // Average number of votes in all products
 $avg_rating = 3.7; // Average rating for all products
$this_num_votes = 6; // Number of votes for this product
 $this_rating = 4; // Rating for this product


$bayesian_rating = ( ($avg_num_votes * $avg_rating) + ($this_num_votes * $this_rating) ) /    ($avg_num_votes + $this_num_votes);

echo round($bayesian_rating); // 3
```

What is the significance of 3? What is the highest possible rating?

Comment: Is your question about basic arithmetic?

Comment: Not sure. What would the rating 3 be out of? like rating: 3 out of 10

Comment: The question is: what's the significance of "3". What does it mean, practically. How can it be used, applied, compared, etc.

Comment: @Chris  That sounds like the best question to ask, so I edited it.

Comment: I think the this_rating will have a highest possible value of 10. Am I correct?

Comment: no, you're not correct. There is no way of knowing what the highest possible value is with the information you've provided. It could be 4 and everything is getting good ratings, it could be 100 and everything is getting poor ratings. But with what we have here, we can't tell.

Comment: @Bob Baddeley Do you have any suggestions as to how I can implement this?

Comment: You've implemented the formula for bayesian rating correctly. It's supposed to dampen the ratings based on the number of votes so that a single positive vote for a product doesn't skyrocket it to the top of the list of products. If you're making a list of top products by their rating, you don't sort by their average rating but by their bayesian rating.

Comment: $this_rating is the average rating of the current product? correct?

Comment: @wenbert yes that is the avg usually x / 5 for the current product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're comparing the ratings for this product against the ratings in all products, so your answer is a rating. If $avg_rating and $this_rating are 3.7 and 4 out of 10, then your answer is out of 10. If it's out of 5, then your answer is out of 5. $bayesian_rating, $avg_rating, and $this_rating are all comparable.

Comment: Because the highest possible rating is either 5 or 10?

Comment: no, it's whatever the highest possible rating for $avg_rating and $this_rating is. If those are 5 stars, 10 thumbs up, 100 rotten tomatoes, whatever. They're all three the same scale.

Comment: So this problem would be the 3 out of 10? I still do not understand.

Comment: You know how movie ratings give two thumbs up (out of two possible thumbs), or 5 stars out of 5 stars on netflix, or on rotten tomatoes it's % (out of 100%)? Those all have units attached to them and tell you what the max is. Nothing in your question gave us the units or the means of deriving the units. We don't, and can't, know what the highest rating is without more information.

Comment: For this script, Can I factor in the highest possible rating? Or would it not work?

Comment: Why do you need to? You're making this harder than it is. What is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: @BobBaddeley let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1326/discussion-between-rpm-and-bob-baddeley)

Answer (score 1):

Well, working out your math:

```
((18 * 3.7) + (6 * 4)) / (18 + 6)
(66.6 + 24) / (24)
90.6 / 24
3.775
```

So it's 3 out of 1...